# How can I add a trailing singleton dimension to a matrix

Tags: matlab, mex

As the title says, how can I add a trailing singleton dimension to a matrix in Matlab?

`A=ones(3,3,1);` gives a 3x3 matrix, while `A=ones(1,3,3);` gives a 1x3x3 matrix

Adding to the specific problem:

I have an application where I have N MxM matrices and I need to stack them, the result becoming a MxMxN matrix. However, N can be 1, and if it is, I need the matrix to be MxMx1.

Note: I am aware that this makes little sense for Matlab scripts, as [Loren suggested](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/293216), in Matlab there are infinite "singleton" dimensions after non singleton ones. However, this is otherwise in the mex environment, where `mxGetNumberOfDimensions` is used.

Comment: I thought a 3x3 matrix and a 3x3x1 3D array were really the same in Matlab. Isn't that the case in mex files?

Comment: Have you tried simply reshaping it to `[M M 1]`?

Comment: @LuisMendo In mex files all data is (as it is internally in Matlab) a 1D array with dimensions data attached to it. While codding a mex wrapper, if you need to check if the data is correctly input, you need functions like `mxGetNumberOfDimensions` or `mxGetDimensions`. If an input has to be 3D but one of the dimensions can be 1, then `mxGetNumberOfDimensions==3` can not be used!

Comment: @AndrasDeak I tried indeed. Does not work.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Can't you just use `mxGetNumberOfDimensions<=3`? That would automatically declare an MxNx1 array as valid

Comment: @AnderBiguri, it works if the singleton is not the final one. Unfortunately it gets squeezed automatically if it's in the last position... There has to be a way. Probably with `bsxfun`;)

Comment: @LuisMendo but if `mxGetNumberOfDimensions<3` then the user is inputing the data wrongly! Unless N=1, then is good. Basically I want the user to be very explicit of how its using my mex code, so if N=1, then the user needs to make sure there are 3dims.

Comment: @AnderBiguri So `N` is defined in advance? Can't you then use `if (N>1 && mxGetNumberOfDimensions==3) || (N==1 && mxGetNumberOfDimensions==2)`?

Comment: @LuisMendo I could, but N is not that easy to get in that part of the code. Basically I have a 400~ lines mex wrapper whos only purpose is to check if the inputs are correct, and then pass them to C. I could rearrange the whole code to get `N` earlier and then be able to do that, but its complicated. I also like the idea of "forcing" the user to do the rigth thing, so he/she learns how to use it properly. If this question has no solution, I will do what you suggested, but I preffer to add a singleton dimension.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the question then is, can mex distinguish between MxM and MxMx1? (Matlab can't)

Comment: @LuisMendo mex can. If the matrix were MxMx1, then `mxGetNumberOfDimensions=3`. My question is more if Matlab can do it.

Comment: Matlab's `ndim` function reads `Trailing singleton dimensions are ignored.` which suggests that it's possible to add singleton dimensions to arrays, or that sentence would be futile. I wouldn't know how though... Good question. For the moment, I would look for a solution on mex' site.

Comment: You say "I also like the idea of "forcing" the user to do the rigth thing, so he/she learns how to use it properly." -it sounds like you also want to force the user to do something in a non-Matlab way. In Matlab MxM is the same as MxMx1. Don't make more work for yourself. Just detail this in your help/documentation as is likely done for many built-in functions.

Comment: @horchler I may go that way, still I am interested if it is possible.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Regarding "_If the matrix were MxMx1, then mxGetNumberOfDimensions=3._", I do not think this is correct.  Can you demonstrate this?

Comment: @JJMDriessen I don't think that suggests that.  What it suggests is that there are an infinite number of *implicit* trailing singleton dimensions, which are ignored by that function since they don't really exist.  Try `size(M,454235)` for any `M`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The trailing singleton is dropped by MATLAB even from the point of view of the MEX API.  The [**docs for `mxSetDimensions`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxsetdimensions.html#zmw57dd0e27725) say as much:

> MATLAB® automatically removes any trailing singleton dimensions specified in the `dims` argument. For example, if `ndim` equals 5 and `dims` equals [4 1 7 1 1], the resulting array has the dimensions 4-by-1-by-7.

Again, that's from the `mxSetDimensions` docs.

Here's a test to try this with `mxSetDimensions` or `mxCreateNumericArray`:

```
// mexSizeTest.cpp
#include "mex.h"
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    if (nrhs!=1)
        mexErrMsgTxt("Just one input please.");

    mxArray *M = mxDuplicateArray(prhs[0]);
    const mwSize ndimsOrig = mxGetNumberOfDimensions(M);
    const mwSize *dimsOrig = mxGetDimensions(M);

    mexPrintf("Number of dimensions (input): %d\n\n", ndimsOrig);

    const mwSize ndims = ndimsOrig + 1;
    mwSize *dims = (mwSize*) mxMalloc(ndims*sizeof(mwSize));
    for (int i=0; i<ndimsOrig; ++i) dims[i] = dimsOrig[i];
    dims[ndims-1] = 1;

    mexPrintf("Target dimensions: [");
    for (int i=0; i<ndims-1; ++i) mexPrintf("%d ",dims[i]);
    mexPrintf("%d]\n\n",dims[ndims-1]);

    mexPrintf("Reshaping to #dims = %d with trailing singleton.\n", ndims);
    mxSetDimensions(M, dims, ndims);
    mexPrintf("Number of Dimensions: %d\n\n", mxGetNumberOfDimensions(M));

    // Let's be dangerous to see if the 1 is just hiding under the hood
    const mwSize *dimsSet = mxGetDimensions(M);
    mexPrintf("Being dangerous: %d\n\n", dimsSet[ndims-1]); // !!!
    mxDestroyArray(M);

    mexPrintf("Creating fresh mxArray of #dims = %d with trailing singleton.\n",
            ndims);
    M = mxCreateNumericArray(ndims, dims, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
    mexPrintf("Number of Dimensions: %d\n",mxGetNumberOfDimensions(M));
    mxDestroyArray(M); mxFree(dims);
}
```

The MATLAB test:

```
>> M = rand(24,55,1);
>> size(M)
ans =
    24    55
>> ndims(M)
ans =
     2
>> size(M,454235) % note we can check the 454235th dimension
ans =
     1
```

Side note with that `size(M,454235)` test: This is what the `ndim` docs mean when they say `Trailing singleton dimensions are ignored`.  They're really not ignored, they just aren't really there!

The MEX test (mexSizeTest.cpp):

```
>> mexSizeTest(M)
Number of dimensions (input): 2

Target dimensions: [24 55 1]

Reshaping to #dims = 3 with trailing singleton.
Number of Dimensions: 2

Being dangerous: -994713024

Creating fresh mxArray of #dims = 3 with trailing singleton.
Number of Dimensions: 2
```

I suggest to adapt your code to handle the case where `mxGetNumberOfDimensions` returns 2.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Glad that helps.  Note I fixed a mistake (it's now like it is on my machine, not a cut-paste Frankenstein, so the results are still correct).

Answer (score 5):

You can use `permute` to inject a trailing default singleton dimension into a non-trailing position. For instance:

```
A = rand(50,50); % produces a 50 x 50 matrix
B = permute(A, [1 3 2]); % produces a 50 x 1 x 50 array
```

Here, 3 refers to the third dimension in the array, an implicit dimension of size 1.

Comment: No sorry, you missed the point of the question. Also, it was answered and accepted 2 years ago.

Comment: No I am answering the question in the title, which Google used to bring me here before I had the answer. You don't understand SO if you think it matters that an answer was accepted 2 years ago. I'll suffer downvotes from people like you so I can help the next Googler.

Comment: Sorry, I did not meant to offend you. I did ask the question, I know it matters because that is the answer of the question in the body. I should add a word to the title to make it clearer perhaps, but the body asks about a *trailing* singleton dimension. I donwvoted because regardless of what google says, this does not answer the question I asked.

Comment: Thanks jiggunjer. I, too, got here via Google, and your answer is the one I needed.